# AWS Workspace Security Group Egress Requirments

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, networking, amazon-workspaces

I need to restrict some workspaces internet access to approved IPs. The easiest (according to my understanding) would be to modify the d-xxxxxxxxxx_workspacesMembers security group Outbound rules. To test I just removed all Outbound rules (meaning no outbound access), but it seems like the workspace won't start up.

The short question is, where can I find a list of outbound access requirements so that I can whitelist them? All I can find are *client* internet requirements: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/workspaces-port-requirements.html

The longer question is what is the best way to restrict outbound access? I'm not opposed to something like a squid proxy, but our requirements aren't that complex, a simple IP whitelist would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, the right approach would be to use a Firewall Appliance or the AWS Network Firewall (or maybe a endpoint protection) to control the traffic.

From: [Security Groups for Your WorkSpaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces-security-groups.html)

> Do not modify or delete the _controllers and the _workspacesMembers security groups. If you modify or delete these security groups, your WorkSpaces won't function correctly, and you won't be able to recreate these groups and add them back.

Alternatively also windows firewall rules rolled out via GPO should work, but not the best approach from my point of view.